# React router path validation and redirection

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm using [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) with [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) for implementation of SPA.
I want to implement such a UI:

[image: simple UI schema]

The main idea that I have a list of `Entitnes` and if I click on an `Entity`, `url` is changed from `http://domain/entities` to `http://domain/entities/id`, where `id` is an `Entitiy`'s `id` and the specific React component is loaded.

For performing navigation I'm using `push` method from `react-router-redux` but also I can just type a `url` path.
But I need somehow validate `url` params. I want to check for `id`, is it in correct format and does the specific entity exist, and if not, I should rollback `url` to a previous state and then show an error alert.

I guess it is possible to do, but I'm a very beginner in `React`, so I would like to hear any advice from you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Learn about react-router hooks like `onEnter`, etc. You can determine them in your routes.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/Glossary.md#enterhook

Example:

```
var correctDataHandler = function(transition) {
    if( condition )
        transition.redirect('/')
};

var router = ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={ReactRouter.createMemoryHistory()}>
        <Route path="/" component={ AddressForm } />
        <Route path="/map-page" component={ Map } onEnter={ correctDataHandler } />
        <Route path="/select-product-page" component={ CardsList } />
        <Route path="/login" component={ LoginRegisterPage } />
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: And how to check state in onEnter? Can't figure this out.

Comment: @vsync here is newer doc (for v3) `https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/Glossary.md#enterhook`

Comment: From react-router-v4 `onEnter` and similar properties have been removed. [Migrating from v2/v3 to v4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md#on-properties)

Answer (score -1):

Validation for login and router in ReactJs

```
if(this.state.username==="admin" && this.state.password==="1234567")
                    {
                        this.props.history.push("/Welcome");
                    }
```